# how to delete document by field inside collection inside document inside collection on firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have Doctor collection when each doctor (represent by his email ) has a collection called  `patients_waiting`.
Now, what I'm trying to do is **delete** one document from the `paitents_waiting` collection by field calls patients containing his **email**.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

but I tried many solutions and none of them works for me now.
what I have tried to do :

```
Firestore.instance
       .collection("Doctors")
       .document(doctorEmail)
       .collection("paitents_waiting")
       .document(paitentEmail)
       .delete();
```

now it's not good because the document is saved in uid and not by email but I tried to play with the where function but with no success.
**how do I found this document by email and delete him?**

I will mention that I'm doing it on flutter, but I think it doesn't matter.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as long as you have the patient's email address you can search with and delete it

```
 Firestore.instance
            .collection("Doctors")
            . document(doctorEmail)
            .collection("paitents_waiting")
            .where('patient', isEqualTo:paitentEmail )
            .get().then((value) => value.docs.single.reference.delete())
```

Nb: you are using an old version of firestore

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `paitents_waiting` collection, the documents are NOT named according to patient email, they are randomly generated Firebase IDs. Take a closer look.

```
Firestore.instance
       .collection("Doctors")
       .document(doctorEmail)
       .collection("paitents_waiting")
       .document(paitentEmail) //this in your Firebase isn't an email, it's "xaErf43Asd..etc"
       .delete();
```

If you want to follow this approach, which should be working otherwise, when you want to create a patient waiting document, use `.set` instead of `.add`, and set the document id to your pateint's email, like this:

```
Firestore.instance
       .collection("Doctors")
       .document(doctorEmail)
       .collection("paitents_waiting")
       .document(paitentEmail)
       .set({your patient data here});
```

This should get things working for you.

Answer (score 0):

To delete all patients for a doctor by the `email` you can use a combination of Firestore query and batch updates. The first one we need to get all patients with the same email and the other to delete them. A function for that would look like this:

```dart
Future<void> deletePatiensForDoctor(String docEmail, String patEmail) async {
  WriteBatch batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();

  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
      .collection("Doctors")
      .document(docEmail)
      .collection("paitents_waiting")
      .where('email', isEqualTo: patEmail)
      .get();

  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
    batch.delete(doc.reference);
  });

  return batch.commit();
}
```